# React redux - useSelect() and useDispatch() when mapping objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

```
//state.buttons is an array - it is used to map buttons to a menu

function NavMenu() {
  const buttons = useSelector((state) => state.buttons);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const navButtons = buttons.map((button) => {
    const checkDirection = (button) => {
      if (button.pageNo >= button.prevPageNo) {
        dispatch(updateButtonsData({ newDirection: 1 }));
      } else {
        dispatch(updateButtonsData({ newDirection: -1 }));
      }
    };
    checkDirection(button);

    return (
      <li key={button.id} >
          <NavButton buttonData={button} />
      </li>
    );
  });

  return <ul>{navButtons}</ul>;
}

export default NavMenu;


//buttonSlice 

const initialState = [
  {
    id: 'homeId',
    prevPageNo: null,
    pageNo: 1,
    direction: 1,
    firstAnimFrame: 1,
    lastAnimFrame: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 'aboutId',
    prevPageNo: null,
    pageNo: 2,
    direction: 1,
    firstAnimFrame: 1,
    lastAnimFrame: 11,
  },{...}

const buttonsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'ui',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateButtonsData: {
      reducer(state, action) {
        state = action.payload;
      },
      prepare(
        id,
        newPrevPageNo,
        pageNo,
        newDirection,
        newFirstFrame,
        newLastFrame
      ) {
        return {
          payload: {
            id,
            prevPageNo: newPrevPageNo,
            pageNo,
            direction: newDirection,
            firstAnimFrame: newFirstFrame,
            lastAnimFrame: newLastFrame,
};},},},},});
```

Hello, I have a navigation menu where several parameters must be dynamically updated within the UI when a user presses a button. Each button will behave differently depending on the previous button as pressed (order of pressed buttons matters). My solution is to compare the initial state of the nav buttons array to each subsequent remapping. I thought it would be good to store the history of the previously pressed button as a value inside the nav objects array. Each time the navigation is refreshed, new parameters are added and accessible as props inside the mapped button and can then be accessed onClick.

Currently, the dispatch function does not work with my code, and the mapped buttons array remains unchanged.

Comment: can you post what `NavButton ` is?

Comment: shouldn't you check the direction when the button is clicked? right now you are doing it inside a map which doesn't seem correct. if you'd like to make a codesandbox id be happy to help fix the problem.. but its a bit difficult with what you're showing currently

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/poc-redux-ui-statemanagment-szlis?file=/src/ui/NavMenu.js:633-634

here is a sandbox of the POC. I think my approach is fudumentaly flawed. I'm happy to explain anything in there in detail if you need calrification

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are "triggering" the update data via `checkDirection(button);` and not `onClick` Event.

first this is a "no-go" code:

```
  const navButtons = buttons.map((button) => {
    const checkDirection = (button) => {
      if (button.pageNo >= button.prevPageNo) {
        dispatch(updateButtonsData({ newDirection: 1 }));
      } else {
        dispatch(updateButtonsData({ newDirection: -1 }));
      }
    };
    checkDirection(button);

    return (
      <li key={button.id} >
          <NavButton buttonData={button} />
      </li>
    );
  });

  return <ul>{navButtons}</ul>;
}
```

If you want to trigger a function while rendering an element, put it inside useEffect and not "outside".

So, transfer that code inside NavButton like:

```
    const checkDirection = useCallback(button) => {
      if (button.pageNo >= button.prevPageNo) {
        dispatch(updateButtonsData({ newDirection: 1 }));
      } else {
        dispatch(updateButtonsData({ newDirection: -1 }));
      }
    }, []);

   useEffect(() => checkDirection(button), [checkDirection, button]);
```

Comment: your `useEffect` needs a dependency array or it has no benefit. remember `useEffect(..., [])` is the same as `componentDidMount`.